# Word meaning start (beginning) of military service

Tags: word-request, idiom-request

Is there a special word or proverb meaning the beginning of military service? Maybe something like "to put on the uniform"?

Comment: Of your own free will: you "enlist". Of the military doing it to you of your own free will: you get "recruited". Of the military doing it to you whether you like it or not: you get "drafted".

Comment: You need to make it clear if you want AmE or BrE idioms (or other forms of English usage). Idioms vary wildly from country to country, especially military idioms.

Answer (score 2):

The best single word for "to enter military service" is probably to [enlist](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enlist).  *Enlistment* is the process of joining.  For example,

> What Does Enlistment Mean?
>
> Enlistment is the process of taking an oath of U.S. Army service and becoming a Soldier. 
>   (from ["Enlisting in the Army"](http://www.goarmy.com/about/serving-in-the-army/types-of-soldiers/enlisted-soldier.html))

Comment: I guess OP is looking for some idiomatic/informal expressions.

Answer (score 2):

In the UK, we have [*join up*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/join-up) and [*sign up*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sign-up). There is no difference in meaning and both terms are in current use. Do not use [*sign on*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sign-on), however. This means to apply for social security payments when you are unemployed.

There is also the phrase *to take the king's shilling* (or *queen's shilling*). This was used when British soldiers and sailors were given a payment when they enlisted. The practice stopped in 1879 and the term is now rarely used. However, the phrase may be useful if you are writing about colonial times.

[Wikipedia: King's shilling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King%27s_shilling)

Answer (score 1):

You may consider the following idiomatic expressions:

***to [muster in](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/muster)***:

> - To enlist or be enlisted in military service: ***She mustered in at the age of 18.***

***to muster out***:

> - To discharge or be discharged from military service: He was mustered out when the war ended.

AHD

Comment: This is not used in BrE (although *muster* is used in other contexts, e.g. to muster some courage).

Answer (score 0):

Good question.  A "recruit" is a new serviceman, who would have been voluntarily "recruited" -- but this doesn't indicate the actual start of service, just the process of joining the service.  If you are *involuntarily* forced into military service, you are "drafted" or "conscripted" into service, and can be called a "draftee" or "conscript".

Otherwise I don't know of any words that relate to the actual start of service, other than "enter".

Edit:  See "enlist", "muster in", "join up", and "sign up" above.